# how to add random Integers to ArrayList without duplication

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, random

I have this empty Array List.
I wanted to add 6 randomly generated integers (1 to 6) but I don't want it to be duplicated.
 Somehow I cannot manage to create loop for that.
I keep getting duplicated values, and even the size of Array List keep changing.
here is my code.
Thanks in advance.

```
    ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

    int rnd = new Random().nextInt(6)+1;

    while(!(al.contains(rnd))){

                for(int i=0; i<=5; i++){

                    al.add(rnd);
                    rnd = new Random().nextInt(6)+1;

                }

                rnd = new Random().nextInt(6)+1;

    }

    System.out.print(al);
```

Comment: Have a look at the .contains() method of the `ArrayList`.

Comment: Why don't you use `Set`? Which doesn't allow duplicates

Comment: Add to `Set` and then convert to `ArrayList`.

Comment: Put the numbers 1-6 into the list and shuffle it.

Comment: Here is the thing. When I use Set ( HashSet) it is giving the output in ascending order  because the integer size is too small. it is always giving [1,2,3,4,5,6]. I believe that's how HashSet works. But, I need unordered way. Thanks for the replies though. I could use shuffle(), but I need it to first add a random integer in my range, then create another random number add it if its not already in the list, and repeat it till 6. No shuffling.

Answer (score 0):

Get all the values in LIST and then put that list in the Set (duplicates are not allowed in Set.)